# Get value from an element using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I need to get the value from one element using several others as filters using Selenium on a dynamic website ([LogTrail](https://github.com/sivasamyk/logtrail) using [Kibana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibana)).

I got this:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os

path2driver_ffox = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), "geckodriver")
path2driver_chr = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()), "chromedriver")

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path2driver_chr)
except:
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path2driver_ffox)

driver.get("https://log-viewer.mob.dev/app/logtrail#/?q=%22lw-00005%22&h=web-sockets&t=Now&i=filebeat-*&_g=()")
print(driver.title)

driver.maximize_window()
```

Using the example below, I need to get the value from the last action where time = 28-2-2022 and lbl-00005 in *li**

How can I do it?

```html
<li id="IavYP38BMeu2l4fa6DvW" ng-repeat="event in events" on-last-repeat="" infinite-scroll="">
    <time>2022-02-28 10:20:49,864</time>
    <span class="host"><a href="" ng-click="onHostSelected(event.hostname)">ws-web-sockets-pp</a></span>
    <span class="program"><a ng-click="onProgramClick(event.program)">/web/serv/logs/ws/ws.log:</a></span>
    <span class="message" ng-style="event.color? {color: event.color} : ''" ng-bind-html="event.message | ansiToHtml" compile-template="">2022-02-28 10:20:49,279 ws-web-sockets-pp-1 INFO  [null:-1] (executor-thread-14) - stat : <span class="highlight">lbl-00005</span>:icifYWZuBe89EUYnMe-J3vIGOWQpG45-66vaB86d, MessageId: 894912413, request message: {"action":"act_VALUE","messageId":"894912413","type":"CALL","uniqueId":"894912413","payload":"{}"}</span>
</li>
```

This works, but:

```python
time = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[ng-repeat='event in events']>time"))).text
```

How do I know if this is the last (newest) record? How do I get the act_VALUE?

This

```python
message = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[ng-repeat='event in events'] .message"))).text
```

It doesn’t seem to input the message that belongs to the time that we get the above.

I can’t copy this and can only send an image :(

[image]

I need to be able to search this page like this.

Get the latest heartbeat (most recent record) and from that heartbeat, get the message id.

This print is with a filter only to show one record, and normally there are thousands of *li* elements.

I need to able to put in a variable like this:

```json
req=" {"action":"Heartbeat","messageId":"33","type":"CALL","uniqueId":"33","payload":"{}"}"

type="heartbeat"

msgid="33"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
# Locate the <li> element by its ID, assuming that
# it has a unique ID ("IavYP38BMeu2l4fa6DvW")
li_element = driver.find_element_by_id("IavYP38BMeu2l4fa6DvW")

# Locate all <time> elements inside the <li> element.
# There may be multiple <time> element found,
# we will store the result in a array.
time_elements = li_element.find_elements_by_tag_name("time")

# Assume that the <time> element that contain
# the time is the first result.
time_element = time_elements[0]

# Access the innerHTML of the <time> element
# The result should be 2022-02-28 10:20:49,864
time_string = time_element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

If you don't know the ID of the `<li>` element, you can try to locate it with [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath). Example:

```
li_xpath = "Input XPath expression here"
li_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Comment: @iLitlewizard thanks, but i dont know the li_element, this is an example, for example the next element id is id="eqvZP38BMeu2l4faY-wA"

Comment: maybe from the <ul class="events">

Comment: See the updated answer @jackl

Comment: having some dificulties with xpath :s your example is a little confusing will have to google a little more but my idea is to loop thru the li_element and add them to a list maybe?

Comment: Just click Ctrl + I to inspect elements, then right click on the element (In the Dev tab) and select "Copy > Copy XPath" on the right click menu. Now the XPath of that element is copied into your clipboard

Comment: nice tip thanks :), but still, i need to get some reading done, i never worked with xpath :(

Answer (score 0):

To handle the dynamic element, use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibility_of_element_located()` and the following CSS selector.

```
time = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[ng-repeat='event in events']>time"))).text

print(time)

chart = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[ng-repeat='event in events'] .message .highlight"))).text

print(chart)
```

You need to import the following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: thanks i get data but i need to understand and learn how to organize it. this is complicated.... updated my post

Comment: @jackl, I hope you have got the answer to your problem. Could you mark it accepted and vote for it.

Comment: not yet, i get the data but i its not matching :s

Comment: @Jackl: your url is not accessible at my location and answered based on html you have provided if you need to get exact answer you need to provide full page html and then post your expected output from the same.

Comment: added info to my original post. thanks

Comment: Is the space near "`.message`" intentional?